# How to pass address of objects created in a C# List to C++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dll, pass-by-reference

I have been looking all over google to find some answers to my questions but do not quite understand what I have found. I have some objects which are created and stored in C# List after using System.IO to read some text files. After that, I want to send references (using const pointers) to each of these objects to the internal classes in C++ dll so that it can use them for computation of some algorithms.

Here are some simple example (not actual code) of what I am doing:

The C# class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class SimpleClass
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string           Name;
    public float            Length;
}
```

with corresponding C struct:

```
struct SimpleClass
{
    const char* Name;
    float Length;
};
```

stored in

```
List<SimpleClass> ItemList;
```

after parsing some text files.

Then calling the following dll function:

C#:

```
[DllImport("SimpleDLL")]
public static extern void AddSimpleReference(SimpleClass inSimple);
```

C:

```
void AddSimpleReference(const SimpleClass* inSimple)
{
   g_Vector.push_back(inSimple); // g_Vector is a std::vector<const SimpleClass* > type
}
```

What I have tried is:

```
for(int i=0; i<ItemList.Count;++i)
{
    SimpleClass theSimpleItem = ItemList[i];
    AddSimpleReference(theSimpleItem);
}
```

Initially, I thought it would be easy to get a actual reference/address just by using the assignment operator since classes in C# are passed-by-reference but it turns out that the C++ class is always pushing the same address value (the address value of the temp reference) into the container instead of the actual address. How do I get the actual object addresses and send it to C++ DLL so that it can have read-only access to the C# objects?

**UPDATE**: Sorry to those who posted answers with unsafe codes. I forgot to mention that the C# code is actually used as a script in Unity game engine which does not allow the use of unsafe codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to change your interop signature to take a pointer (and thus making it unsafe).

```
[DllImport("SimpleDLL")]
public unsafe static extern void AddSimpleReference(SimpleClass* inSimple);
```

Then, because the GC is free to move objects around in memory as it pleases, you will need to pin the object in memory for the *entire* time you will need its address on the unmanaged side. For that you need the `fixed` statement:

```
SimpleClass theSimpleItem = ItemList[i];
unsafe
{
    fixed(SimpleClass* ptr = &theSimpleItem)
    {
        AddSimpleReference(ptr);
    }
}
```

This would work if `AddSimpleReference` used the pointer and then discarded it. But you're storing the pointer in a `std::vector` for later. That won't work, because the pointer will probably become invalid due to the GC moving the original item somewhere else once execution leaves the `fixed` block.

To solve this, you need to pin the items until you are done with them. To do this you may need to resort to the [`GCHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx) type.

```
// Change the interop signature, use IntPtr instead (no "unsafe" modifier)
[DllImport("SimpleDLL")]
public static extern void AddSimpleReference(IntPtr inSimple);

// ----
for(int i=0; i<ItemList.Count;++i)
{
    SimpleClass theSimpleItem = ItemList[i];
    // take a pinned handle before passing the item down.
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(theSimpleItem, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    AddSimpleReference(GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle));
    // probably a good idea save this handle somewhere for later release
}

// ----
// when you're done, don't forget to ensure the handle is freed
// probably in a Dispose method, or a finally block somewhere appropriate
GCHandle.Free(handle);
```

When doing something like this, keep in mind that pinning objects in memory for a long time is a bad idea, because it prevents the garbage collector from doing its job efficiently.

Comment: Is the "full code" for allocating and storing theSimpleItem like this?

SimpleClass theSimpleItem;
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(theSimpleItem, GCHandleType.Pinned);
m_ItemList.Add(theSimpleItem);
?

Comment: I think my understanding is clearer with your last edit. The m_ItemList can be filled by the typical C# new instructions and **then after** that we can grab a pinned handle from each SimpleClass object in the list. Am I right?

Comment: @fisyher: Martin told me to tell you: 'Yes.'

Answer (score 1):

Even though I think this is not a good idea, have a look at unsafe code and memory pinning. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a good start on MSDN.

[fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keywords are likely what you should be looking for.

Comment: I cannot use unsafe code because the C# code is actually used as scripts in Unity game engine, which does not allow the use of "unsafe" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The C# GC will move objects for fun. Your addresses will go out of scope.

Comment: I have read about options like GCHandle and gcroot to pin the objects created but they seem to complicate the codes by a great deal and storing pinned objects for entire duration of the app is not encouraged due to performance issues I'm not very clear about.

If using GCHandle is the only way and I do not want to use it, I guess I would need to re-design my classes. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Memory pinning can be used to fix objects in place, so garbage collection will not compact/move those objects.