# Call C++ from C# Array MarshalAs Problems?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling

So I have a function inside of a C++ library:

```
double MyFunc(double** data, int length)
{
    //data elements are accessed like this
    (*data)[i] = 5.0;
}
```

In C# I access this function in this way:

```
//import
[DllImport(@"MYDLL.dll")]
public static extern double MyFunc(ref double[] data, int length);
//usage
MyFunc(ref data, data.Length);
```

This is silly since I would rather write:

```
double MyFunc(double* data, int length)
{
    //data elements are accessed like this
    data[i] = 5.0;
}
```

The problem is, I do not know how I could access the desired C++ function from C#...I am not well versed in Marshaling values...How would I do this?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341023/how-to-pass-address-of-objects-created-in-a-c-list-to-c-dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass a `double[]` directly.

Comment: I should probably congratulate myself for not trying the most obvious thing in the WORLD. :| (Thank you for your help)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking bout how to create that *same function* in `c#`, then you are asking about `unsafe` code in C# check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

your code would be:

```
unsafe double MyFunc(double* data, int length)
{
    //data elements are accessed like this
    data[i] = 5.0;
}
```